# xcode8 coding issue with tutorial getting error for method 'setplayer'

Tags: swift3, xcode8

so I'm trying to follow a tutuorial and I finished most of it but I still keep getting error messages here and don't know how to fix them.

I get an error message that reads

> method'setplayer' with Objective-C selector 'setPlayer:' conflicts
>   with setter for 'player' with the same Objective-C selector

```
import UIKit

class TTTImageView: UIImageView {

    var player:String?
    var activated:Bool! = false

    func setPlayer (_ _player:String){ "<-- error message for this line of code"
        self.player = _player

        if activated == false{
            if _player == "x"{
                self.image = UIImage(named: "x")
            }else{
                self.image = UIImage(named: "o")
            }
            activated = true
        }

    }
}
```

Answer with source code would be amazing thanks.

Comment: The error message seems to explain your problem precisely. A setter for a property "player" will be called "setPlayer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Just rename the method from `setPlayer` to something else like `placePlayer` and you'll be fine.

**Reason:**

Since Swift and Objective-C are interoperable, the Objective-C translation of your Swift code must be valid as well. In Objective-C, properties have automatically generated setters with the name `set` followed by the name of the property. Your function conflicts with this automatically generate function, so you get an error.

**Code:**

```
class TTTImageView: UIImageView {

    var player: String?
    var activated: Bool = false

    func placePlayer(_ _player: String) {
        self.player = _player

        if activated == false {
            if _player == "x" {
                self.image = UIImage(named: "x")
            } else {
                self.image = UIImage(named: "o")
            }
            activated = true
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If my solution worked for you, mark it as "accepted" so if others run into the same issue in the future, they'll be able to find the solution quickly.